# Fourier Transform: If $H(\alpha)=e^{-t\alpha^{2}}F(\alpha)$, what is $h(x)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I am trying to solve the following problem from my textbook:

> If $f(x) \in L^{2}(-\infty, \infty)$ has Fourier transform
>   $F(\alpha)$, then what is the function of $x$ whose transform is the
>   function $H(\alpha)=e^{-t\alpha ^{2}}F(\alpha)$? ($t$ is a positive real constant).

The answer given in the back of the book is $\displaystyle h(x) =  \left[4 \pi t\right]^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp \left[\frac{-(x-y)^{2}}{4t} \right]f(y)dy$, but I have no idea how they got that.

I attempted the problem by writing that $\displaystyle h(x) = e^{-t\alpha^{2}}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\alpha}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) e^{-t\alpha^{2}-ix\alpha} dx$, but from that point on, I don't know what to do.

Is this possibly a situation where a convolution is involved? Or is it some kind of a translation? I am really lost, and am trying to teach these things to myself. **Could somebody please help me understand what's going on here, and how to get the solution the book has?**

Thank you.

Comment: An important fact is that Fourier transform of the convolution of two functions is the product of the Fourier transforms of those two functions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers so this is a convolution problem? How would I be able to tell this by looking at the problem?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I also have never actually worked out a Fourier transform problem that requires convolution. More details would probably be more helpful should you be willing to provide them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can write the Fourier Transform of the convolution, $\mathscr{F}\{f*g\}=\mathscr{F}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')g(x-x')\,dx'\right)$, between two functions $f$ and $g$ as

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f*g\}(\alpha)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')g(x-x')\,dx'\right)\,e^{i\alpha x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x')\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-x')e^{i\alpha x}\,dx\right)\,dx'\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x')\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x'')e^{i\alpha (x'+x'')}\,dx''\right)\,dx'\\\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x')e^{i\alpha x'}\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x'')e^{i\alpha x''}\,dx''\right)\\\\
&=\left(\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\alpha)\right)\left(\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\alpha)\right)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Let $F(\alpha)=\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\alpha)$ and $e^{-t\alpha^2}=G(\alpha)=\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\alpha)$ in $(1)$.  Therefore, the inverse Fourier Transform $\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{F(\alpha)G(\alpha)\}$ of $F(\alpha)G(\alpha)$ is given by $f*g$.  Since $g$ is the inverse Fourier Transform of $e^{-t\alpha^2}$, then $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-x^2/(4t)}$ and we have

$$(f*g)(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x')e^{-(x-x')^2/(4t)}\,dx'$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Wow @Dr.MV you make it seem so easy!

Comment: you are so awesome. Could you help me with this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093726/find-bounds-on-a-solution-to-diffusion-equation-with-lower-order-terms-and-inhom